# .java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: algorithm RSA/PKCS1 is not available from provider Cryptix

Tags: java, rsa

I am using `jdk1.7_60` and `apache tomcat`

I deployed my web application I got following error

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: algorithm RSA/PKCS1 is not available from provider Cryptix
        at xjava.security.IJCE.getClassCandidate(IJCE.java:463)
        at xjava.security.IJCE.getImplementationClass(IJCE.java:416)
        at xjava.security.IJCE.getImplementation(IJCE.java:373)
        at xjava.security.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:492)
        at xjava.security.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:455)
        at COM.claymoresystems.ptls.SSLClientKeyExchange.encode(SSLClientKeyExchange.java:77)
        at COM.claymoresystems.ptls.SSLHandshake.sendHandshakeMsg(SSLHandshake.java:149)
        at COM.claymoresystems.ptls.SSLHandshake.sendHandshakeMsg(SSLHandshake.java:144)
        at COM.claymoresystems.ptls.SSLHandshakeClient.sendClientKeyExchange(SSLHandshakeClient.java:400)
        at COM.claymoresystems.ptls.SSLHandshakeClient.processTokens(SSLHandshakeClient.java:148)
        at COM.claymoresystems.ptls.SSLHandshake.processHandshake(SSLHandshake.java:135)
        at org.globus.gsi.gssapi.GlobusGSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GlobusGSSContextImpl.java:483)
        at org.globus.gsi.gssapi.net.GssSocket.authenticateClient(GssSocket.java:102)
        at org.globus.gsi.gssapi.net.GssSocket.startHandshake(GssSocket.java:140)
        at org.globus.gsi.gssapi.net.GssSocket.getOutputStream(GssSocket.java:161)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:433)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:135)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2745)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2728)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2405)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2327)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1767)
        at org.nimbustools.messaging.gt4_0.generated.WorkspaceFactoryPortTypeSOAPBindingStub.create(WorkspaceFactoryPortTypeSOAPBindingStub.java:1224)
        at org.globus.workspace.client_core.actions.Create.createImpl(Create.java:575)
        at org.globus.workspace.client_core.actions.Create.create(Create.java:497)
```

Please help me how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance. Its very important issue to fix.

Thanks 
kalasagar

Answer (score 2):

it's not able to find algorithm if you give it like `RSA/PKCS1`.You need to specify whether you want to use mode or not .Try with `RSA/None/PKCS1Padding`

Comment: where i need to add RSA/None/PKCS1Padding ? where i need to specify